# SQL Server - change column if existing in other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Playing around with SQL Server 2008 and I have a table `People` with columns:

```
Name  | City |  Born | ...
```

and another table `Change` with columns:

```
OldName  |  NewName
```

Now I would like to change `Name` in the table `People` something like this: if there is the same `OldName` in table `Change` as the `Name` in `People` then change the `Name` in `People` to the `NewName` in `Change`.

Any easy way?

Oh and another question to this: if the `Name` in `People` would be the primary key (or let say `Name` and `City` would be composite key), would it be much harder to change the name? Thx

Comment: If `Name` is part of the primary key, it's by default part of the clustering key (the key by which your table is physically ordered). Changing that value would cause the table structure to be changed, it would require all non-clustered indices on that table to be rebuilt .... **not** a good idea! And what about all child tables that reference that primary key? How are you updating those?? The primary key is best kept unchanged, once it's defined.

Comment: So if Person would be the primary key, there would be no way to solve this solution right?

Comment: There are ways to solve it - but none are very straightforward and easy to do ..... I would try to avoid this at all cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer1)

```
UPDATE people,change
SET people.name = change.newname
WHERE people.name = change.oldName
```

**EDIT** with inner Join syntax:

```
UPDATE people
SET people.name = change.newName
FROM people
INNER JOIN change ON people.name = change.oldName
```

I don't have a SQL Server to test that on, but based on online examples, it should work.

**/Edit**

Answer2) As long as you still maintain uniqueness in the key it wouldn't be difficult to change at all. As soon as you cause a collision you would get an error. For this reason it would be best to have an auto-incrementing ID field in people that would be your PK

Comment: About #2: oh really?!?!? And what happens to child tables that reference that primary key that you're about to change?? Changing the primary key is **never** a good idea .....

Comment: people,change = syntax error. Somehow its not that easy with ms sql server to do that. I need INNER JOIN and ON ...

Comment: @marc - I wholeheartedly agree that PKs shouldn't be changed, but the question wasn't "should" it was "would it be difficult"

Comment: @miri - updating my answer with inner join syntax but I don't have a SQL Server to test it on, so I can't be sure it's going to be exactly right for SQL Server.

Comment: @invertedSpear no its fine, thats how it works thx. Im just wondering why sql server is forcing me to use such a long and complocated query.

Comment: @miri - Technically this is the correct way to do it, as defined in the SQL language. The first method MySQL lets you get away with, probably from being an open source project where someone wanted to write lazy queries and had the ability to add the feature. MySQL has actually gotten more strict about join syntax in the last few versions, this is probably a good thing as it makes the sql easier for a human to understand exactly what the DB is going to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off to add a `PeopleId` column to the `People` table, and replace the `OldName` column in the `Change` table with a `PeopleId` column that has a foreign key relationship back to the `People` table:

People:

```
PeopleId | Name   | City     | Born
-------------------------------------------
1        | Fred   | New York | 1/1/1980
2        | Wilma  | Boston   | 1/1/1980
```

Change:

```
PeopleId | NewName
----------------------
1        | Barney
```